# Extending collection without class body

Tags: java, collections

I need in my program collection in collection in collection. So something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
```

You can see this does not look good. Mainly when i am using a lot of generics. So i created something like this:

```
public class ThreeDimensionArray extends ArrayList<TwoDimensionArray> { }

class TwoDimensionArray extends ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> { }
```

is this solution bad in some way or is it ok?

Comment: @sp00m You can implement a concrete instance of a class?  Or are you advocating for a switch to `List`?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Implement `java.util.List`, nest an `ArrayList`, and delegate every `List` operation to your nested list.

Comment: @sp00m `implements` serves inheritance, as well. It has nothing to do with composition.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan You're right, I didn't express myself as I meant to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not great, but it is ok. It's rather masking what you are doing - and its a bit wasteful as you are creating a concrete class to define something that type erasure would have turned into a standard List at compile time.

Really you should be using List rather than ArrayList and the diamond operator, both changes will make the original tidier:

```
List<List<List<String>>> 3dList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you do go down the defined class route at least use generics -

```
class TwoDimensionArray<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> { }
```

Then you can use it for multiple types.